# How to view the Tableau workbook in server mode before publishing?

Tags: server, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Some of the modifications made in the Tableau workbook are not being reflected when published into the server. I am wondering how to view it in server-mode before publishing it to make the appropriate changes instead of re-publishing it all over again to make the changes. I am using Tableau version 2021.1.1 Attached are the images of inside the workbook versus the published version. Any feedback will help, thank you[image: server]
[image: workbook]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common issue.

What font are you using?

This blog seems to cover a lot of font issues:
https://www.flerlagetwins.com/2020/08/fonts.html

Specifically, I would pick a web-safe font, which it refers to here:
https://blog.hubspot.com/website/web-safe-html-css-fonts

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I think the issue is what shows on the server-side differs from what shows in the Tableau app; have you came across this issue and is there a way to view it first in server-mode without having to publish it?